# Delphi 11.2 Bluetooth permision not granted

Tags: android, delphi, bluetooth

Running on an Android 12 device.
Worked fine in Delphi 11.1.

I have two apps in use.
In only one of the two, I can not seem to get Bluetooth permision granted.
I have set the Fine Location, which is accepted on initial install.
I only require basic Bluetooth, and Bluetooth Admin.
When going through the requests one at the time (instead of all in one go) this fails permanently:

```
PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([cPermissionBluetooth], TakeBluetoothPermissionsResultHandler, DisplayRationale);
```

And, the DisplayRationale never works at all.
During startup, there is no other User request from the system.

In Setup>Apps there is no specific reference to Bluetooth.
It does not tell me *why* it fails.
According to
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions
I have got all related settings okay (including the Location).
Targeting 'android:maxSdkVersion="30"' which is set by the compiler as default.

In my other App, which is much more complicated, with the *same* Bluetooth/Location settings, it works normally.

What could I have missed?

UPDATE:
I now changed the code to this:

```
const
cPermissionBluetooth = 'android.permission.BLUETOOTH';
  cPermissionBluetoothAdmin = 'android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN';
  cPermissionBluetoothConnect = 'android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT';
  cPermissionBluetoothScan = 'android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN';

procedure TMainForm.TakeBluetoothPermissionsResultHandler(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray; const AGrantResults: TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray);
begin
  // if TGrantResults(AGrantResults).AreAllGranted then
  if PermissionsService.IsPermissionGranted(cPermissionBluetooth) then
  begin
    DoLog('cPermissionBluetooth: Granted');
  end else
  begin
    DoLog('cPermissionBluetooth: NOT Granted!',d_error);
  end;

  if PermissionsService.IsPermissionGranted(cPermissionBluetoothConnect) then
  begin
    DoLog('cPermissionBluetoothConnect: Granted');
  end else
  begin
    DoLog('cPermissionBluetoothConnect: NOT Granted!',d_error);
  end;

  if PermissionsService.IsPermissionGranted(cPermissionBluetoothScan) then
  begin
    DoLog('cPermissionBluetoothScan: Granted');
  end else
  begin
    DoLog('cPermissionBluetoothScan: NOT Granted!',d_error);
  end;
end;
```

And what happens is that the basic android.permission.BLUETOOTH is NOT granted, but the other two are. And Bluetooth actually works.
Does this mean that I am NOT allowed to call android.permission.BLUETOOTH if running on Android 12 or higher? And that I now must specifically look at the Android version, and NOT call that when 12 or higher??

Why does it work normally in my primary App then..?

Right now, I cannot call 'Are all Permissionas Granted' because one fails all the time.
PS: Why can I not use the build-in "TPermissionsService.IsEveryPermissionGranted"? It is imcompatible with its own Android code!

UPDATE2:
The final is like this:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
```

The one which permanently is NOT granted (in Android 12) is: "android.permission.BLUETOOTH".

(I made a mistake in one of my comments about this).

If I ignore this, the Bluetooth does work normally.

Comment: Android 12 requires additional permissions: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions

Comment: That is the link I also have in my question. I do not use any of the options link 'SCAN'. I did try to add the 'BLUETOOTH_CONNECT' but it made no difference. My primary SARTrack App does not have any of these either; I cannot see any difference between the two; But one works and the other keeps failing in Bluetooth, and without any specific warning or action from the OS. I get exactrly the same three questions on install: Access photos & Media; Take pictures; Location (fine). All okay. Then Bluetooth Permision keeps  failing...

Comment: This code: `PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([cPermissionBluetooth]` is requesting only *one* permission.

Comment: Yes, only because of the testing. To be able to detect *which* one is failing. And that is the very one, in Android 12. And I have now changed it again to do them all at the same time; but *excluding* 'BLUETOOTH_CONNECT' because that keeps sayting NO GRANTED. (While the Bluetooth system itself works fine if I ignore it).

Comment: "While the Bluetooth system itself works fine if I ignore it" Does this mean the issue is solved? If not, please check that you have `Bluetooth connect` checked in the Use Permissions list in the Project Options

Comment: I updated the question agin, Update2. The problem is with "android.permission.BLUETOOTH" (NOT with 'CONNECT' as I earlier posted, that was a typo).

Comment: android.permission.BLUETOOTH is not applicable to Android 12, as per the documentation you linked to, so it will not grant it. You need to have a check for the version, e.g. `if TOSVersion.Check(12) then` to exclude that permission when requesting

Comment: It looks that has to be done then.

Comment: Again, does this mean the issue is solved?

Answer (score 3):

I had to change my code like this:

```
if TOSVersion.Major < 12 then
          begin
            LogClient('TOSVersion.Major < 12');
            PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([cPermissionReadExternalStorage,
              cPermissionWriteExternalStorage, cPermissionLocation, cPermissionBluetooth, cPermissionCamera],
              TakeGeneralPermissionsResultHandler, DisplayRationale);
          end else
          begin
            LogClient('TOSVersion.Major >= 12');
            PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([cPermissionReadExternalStorage,
              cPermissionWriteExternalStorage, cPermissionLocation, cPermissionBluetoothConnect, cPermissionBluetoothScan, cPermissionCamera],
              TakeGeneralPermissionsResultHandler, DisplayRationale);
          end;
```